# Elementary OS ATI Graphics

Tags: drivers, elementary-os, ati, graphic-card

I have an Acer Aspire 4820TG. It has an integrated and a dedicated graphics card, the latter is an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650.

The installation of Elementary OS (Luna) went fine but I needed hardware acceleration, so I tried to install ATI drivers from the system settings. Installation went fine but it got stuck on the reboot, somewhere near "checking battery status" or "preload: ".

After some trial and error, involving mess things up with xorg.conf, I managed to get it back where it was before installing the drivers. So I decided to try again but this time no drivers showed up on the settings.

I tried to download the drivers from AMD site, installed them and got the same problem as before, the difference is that now I can't revert it back. I tried to remove all the fglrx packages I had, use the very first xorg.conf I had, but no luck.

How can I make it working again without reinstalling the os? And if it's my only option, what is the best way to install those drivers?

EDIT: updates.
I reinstalled mesa and xserver-xorg-video stuff, now it works but xorg.conf is still messed up, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`doesn't exist (it wasn't recreated automagically?) and the touchpad doesn't work at all too.
However `glxinfo` says it's using direct rendering, but I bet it's still the integrated graphics.

Comment: god help you, the ATI drivers doesn't work well on Unix I don't know why but it is, I had almost same problem and I had to install ubuntu instead.

Comment: @vivian actually a year ago I used ubuntu with ati drivers on the same machine with no problems.

Comment: Is your Integrated Graphics Card Intel Based?  Is VGA Switcharoo enabled in your Kernel, and have you installed the Hybrid Graphics Driver for your platform?

Comment: So I ended up installing Ubuntu 14.10, but still can't install proprietary drivers. However I managed to get Hardware Acceleration going using vesa. Still having some troubles with Steam but I've submitted an issue on the github repo.